# gps using Network provider and gps provider?

Tags: android, gps

Hi, I am trying to get the gps location using location provider and gps provider at the Same time. I am trying for last two days but stil am struggling. I don't know how to do this,I am searching and get this link http://www.hrupin.com/2011/04/android-gps-using-how-to-get-current-location-example, but it's also getting force close. Anybody kindly give working example for gps usind network provider and gps provider

Comment: force close means exception occurred at run time. Check logcat to find the error.

Comment: @yuganthar babu can you give any working Sample

Comment: Here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/android-get-gps-location-via-a-service/8830135#8830135][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/android-get-gps-location-via-a-service/8830135#8830135

I posted an example there

Comment: Please upload your code of activity & AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655

check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is good only. So many examples available in web, one of them is given below.

[Using GPS to get current location – Android tutorial](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/)

I hope it may help you.

Comment: These tutorial is based on one providers only .My question is , using  two providers

Comment: Yes, it is for GPS only, add NETWORK to this by taking help of link you posted in question.