# Use service to get GPS location, android?

Tags: android, service, gps, location

This is first time I am using service and it sure looks a lot complicated from activity.

So I am trying to get the user's location after he has closed my application with the service.

This is my service class.

```
public class LocTrack extends Service {


GPSTracker gp;
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{    gp = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
    onLocationChanged(gp);
    super.onCreate();        
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onLocationChanged(GPSTracker track) {


    // Getting latitude
    double latitude = track.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude
    double longitude = track.getLongitude();

     Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(LocTrack.this, Locale.getDefault());

    try
     {
         List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
         Log.e("Addresses","-->"+addresses);

     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();

     }

}
}
```

Please tell me what am I doing my wrong.
If I use the code in an activity class then I am able to get the address in the logcat but not when i use service.

This is how i am calling the service from activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocTrack.class);
             startService(intent);
```

Comment: Have u implemented permission in manifest

Comment: yes  <service android:name=".LocTrack" />.....LocTrack is the name of my service class

Comment: no M ASKING INTERNET,GPS,Location,Mock

Comment: Yes I had set all the necessary permissions

Comment: Here link is working fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/8830135/1915697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use location services by CWAC 
Location Poller service is already made for us to use it just you have to give the time interval to wake up it

Do it like dis way n you'll need the jar file which you can get it from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pgxk2v9l5vl0h2j/3svyZnuwOK/CWAC-LocationPoller.jar

From your activity start LocationPoller and set the alarm repeating to the time you want

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
LocationPollerParameter parameter = new LocationPollerParameter(bundle);
parameter.setIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion(new Intent(this,
        LocationReceiver.class));
// try GPS and fall back to NETWORK_PROVIDER
parameter.setProviders(new String[] { LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER });
parameter.setTimeout(120000);
i.putExtras(bundle);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 300000, pi);
```

Make a receiver class Location Receiver from where you'll fetch the lat n lon

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    try {      
      Bundle b=intent.getExtras();

      LocationPollerResult locationResult = new LocationPollerResult(b);

      Location loc=locationResult.getLocation();
      String msg;

      if (loc==null) {
        loc=locationResult.getLastKnownLocation();

        if (loc==null) {
          msg=locationResult.getError();
        }
        else {
          msg="TIMEOUT, lastKnown="+loc.toString();
        }
      }
      else {
        msg=loc.toString();



        Log.i("Location Latitude", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
        Log.i("Location Longitude", String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
        Log.i("Location Accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));




      }

      Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "received location: " + msg);   



    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

and add this to your manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

   <receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPoller" />

   <service android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerService" />
```

and the receiver declaration where you'll fetch everything

```
   <receiver android:name="com.RareMediaCompany.Helios.LocationReceiver" />
```

Comment: It is unable to find LocationPollerResult and  LocationPollerParameter....what are these???

Comment: Srry that was an outdated library ...replace the previous one with this n it'll work...[link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pgxk2v9l5vl0h2j/3svyZnuwOK/CWAC-LocationPoller.jar

Comment: I think it's either not working or i have done something wrong.....i copy pasted your code but i am not able to get any location in the logcat...

Comment: Add another log between these lines in your location receiver
Location loc=locationResult.getLocation();
Log.i("Location Latitude", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
      String msg;
and have you declared your receiver in the manifest

Comment: i dont know if am right or wrong i declared like this  <receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver" />....still doesnt work...even delared it with the packeage name

Comment: declare it with the package name and if you are not getting any error that means your code is running fine...just add the log after this line
Location loc=locationResult.getLocation();
like this
Log.i("Location Latitude", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude())); 
and see what comes in this log