# onLocationChanged is never called by using requestLocationUpdates with GPS provider

Tags: android, gps

I'm developing an application by using service to track user's locations and send the data to the server in the background. It's the GPS based app. When my program called requestLocationUpdates with GPS provider, the onLocationChanged is never called. However, the requestLocationUpdates works fine with network provider on my app. Please take a look at my code.

Android version: 4.1.2
Device: Galaxy nexus S

**Tracker.java**

```
private void init() {
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NOTIFICATION = R.string.local_service_started;
    arrivedStatus = false;
    activity = TrackerActivity.getAppActivity();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    init();
    Log.i(tag, "Start Tracking");
    showStartNotification();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    tripID = intent.getExtras().getInt("tripID") + "";
    locationInterval = intent.getExtras().getInt("locationInterval")
            * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
    //lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
    //      locationInterval, 0, locationListener);
    getLocation();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("STOP_SERVICE", "Service has stopped");
    mNM.cancel(R.string.local_service_started);
    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    stopSelf();
}

private void getLocation() {
    lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // getting GPS status
    isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // getting network status
    isNetworkEnabled = lm
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
        // no network provider is enabled
        Log.e(tag, "Non providers are enabled");
    } else {

        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    locationInterval, 0, locationListener);
            Log.d(tag, "GPS Enabled");
        }

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            if (lm == null) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        locationInterval, 0, locationListener);
                Log.d(tag, "Network Enabled");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void showStartNotification() {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the
    // expanded notification
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.cameral, text,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
    // notification+
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, TrackerActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
            getText(R.string.local_service_label), text, contentIntent);

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}

/**
 * private void showStopSpecification() { CharSequence text =
 * getText(R.string.local_service_cancel); Notification notification = new
 * Notification(R.drawable.btn_save_dialog, text,
 * System.currentTimeMillis()); mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification); }
 */

private void checkResult(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                Log.v(tag, "Store data successfully");
                activity.findViewById(R.id.tracker_info)
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue4);
                if (json.getInt(ARRIVED_STATUS) == 1) {
                    setArrivedStatus(true);
                } else {
                    setArrivedStatus(false);
                }
            } else if (json.getString(KEY_ERROR).equals("1")) {
                // Error in login
                String error_msg = json.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG);
                Log.e(tag, error_msg);
                setArrivedStatus(false);
            } else {
                Log.e(tag, "Something is wrong");
                setArrivedStatus(false);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(tag, "Something is wrong");
            setArrivedStatus(false);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setArrivedStatus(boolean status) {
    arrivedStatus = status;
}

public boolean getArrivedStatus() {
    return arrivedStatus;
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentLat = location.getLatitude() + "";
        currentLng = location.getLongitude() + "";
        Log.v(tag, LOCATION_CHANGED + " lat=" + currentLat + ", lon="
                + currentLng);
        try {
            JSONObject json = new LogInfo().execute(
                    new String[] { tripID, currentLat, currentLng }).get();
            checkResult(json);
            if (getArrivedStatus() == true) {
                Log.v(tag, "User has arrived safely");
                onDestroy();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

I also already added the permission to my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call this function, do you see the GPS icon on the notification bar of the device? if so, it means it tries to get a location and you're just in a place with no GPS reception.

in any case, you can use Google's way to get the location, here: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/324498944

also, what is the class "Tracker"? is it a service? if so, you shouldn't let it have a reference to an activity, since it can cause memory leaks. instead use correct binding .

you should also avoid calling "onDestroy" , since calling it doesn't really close your service. instead call "stopSelf", and make sure no activity is bound to it.

if you wish, i've asked this sort of question (of getting a location via a service) a long time ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/android-get-gps-location-via-a-service).

Comment: However, does binding service mean that the service has to stop for a while during performing a binding service method?

Comment: @user2503808 i don't understand the question. the service will be considered stopped only after it really stopped itself, and this will happen only after it doesn't have any live bindings to it. check this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle (scroll to the diagram if you wish) or this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html