# Location Aware Client Library in android

Tags: android, api, client-server, client-library

I am trying to build a client library in android for communicating with a remote server's API.
the library utilized AsyncTasks for the communications , the API requires the device location so i need to access google location services from this library.

```
public class ClientLib{

    private Context context;
    public ClientLib(Context c){
         context = c;
    }

    ... Lots of methods and nested classes ...
}
```

in all of the examples i have seen , the google location services is implemented inside of an activity. i tried copying the code to the library and replacing `this` with `context` and so forth but it seems like i am missing something.

How would you implement a location aware client library that communicates with a remote API ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question but are you trying to get location notifications (lat and lng) from an Android Service and call an API with this retrieved values? 
Something like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/android-get-gps-location-via-a-service)?