# background service android java

Tags: java, android, service, background, locationmanager

I'm developing an android java application,

I'm stuck on a point of how to run a function in the background *even* if the app is closed.

My goal is to get the user location every 30 minutes.

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, starting from android 10, there are more restrictions on accessing location in background.

Comment: You need a foreground service. This will ensure that Android system wont kill your service even if it is in background. Inside the service you can write your logic to fetch the location info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an android app to always run in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use JobIntentService or WorkManager for running the task periodically.

[JobIntentService](https://androidwave.com/working-with-jobintentservice/)

[WorkManager Periodically](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Service** to get user location while the application is in the background.

**And for further implementation you can refer below link:-**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830135/11625897